# How do I limit a P4DIFF to only SQL files?

Tags: diff, perforce

I am running on Server 2008 and scripting a CMD line Diff via Powershell. I have everything working (working, not finished) but I am having trouble figuring out how to limit the output to only SQL files. An example of the Diff:

```
p4.exe diff -S -db -dn 251674 251616 > C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Queries\Output2.txt
```

The first Change List is a SQL only change so the results are in line with what I need but the second is a mix of SQL and C code changes. I am continuing to refine my Diff but I am the DBA so my focus is only on the SQL changes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish my **SQL only Diff** by building separate queries using the entire Depot path and the Revision number. *There is plenty of room for improvement* (such as parsing the information from the first query rather than running all three queries) but I ran out of time as I wanted to use it for today's report. Any helpful suggestions would be appreciated!

I started by using P4Report and querying all of the information from the Files table (lines 1 & 2) that met my criteria and outputting it to a 'Report' text file. This ultimately heads my report in Excel.

P4Report Query:

```
select * from files where RIGHT (FILE,9) = 'chema.sql' and TIME > timestampadd(4, -8, now()) and action in ('add', 'edit', 'integrate') order by time;
```

I then queried for just the Path & File names and stored that in a variable (lines 3 & 4).

P4Report Query:

```
select file from files where RIGHT (FILE,9) = 'chema.sql' and TIME > timestampadd(4, -8, now()) and action in ('add', 'edit', 'integrate') order by time;
```

Lastly I queried for the Revision number and stored that in a variable as well (lines 7 & 8).

P4Report Query:

```
select revision from files where RIGHT (FILE,9) = 'chema.sql' and TIME > timestampadd(4, -8, now()) and action in ('add', 'edit', 'integrate') order by time;
```

I then used a foreach loop to create and execute each of the Perforce Command Line strings and appended the results of each to a '_Diff_Report' text file.

Lastly I removed all of the tabs from the '_Diff_Report' (which makes it a lot cleaner when I import into Excel).

```
$Rpt = '"C:\Program Files\Perforce\P4Report\p4sql.exe" -d ""~"" -i C:\Users\UserName\documents\Queries\DataQ\_Report.txt > C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Queries\Report.txt'
$out = iex "& $Rpt"
$Cmd1 = '"C:\Program Files\Perforce\P4Report\p4sql.exe" -i C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Queries\DataQ\_Files.txt'
$fil = iex "& $Cmd1"
# Debug
# $fil | Out-File C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Queries\_fil_Debug.txt
$Cmd2 = '"C:\Program Files\Perforce\P4Report\p4sql.exe" -i C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Queries\DataQ\_Revisions.txt'
$rev = iex "& $Cmd2"
# Debug
# $rev | Out-File C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Queries\_Rev_Debug.txt
$dt = Get-Date
$dt | Out-File C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Queries\DataQ\_Diff_Report.txt
$f = $fil
$r = $rev
# Debug
# $r | Out-File C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Queries\_R_variable_Debug.txt
$cnt = 2
foreach ($Change in $f)
{
$revision = $r[$cnt] -1
$Cmd3 = '"C:\Program Files\Perforce\p4" diff2 -db '
$Cmd3 = $Cmd3 + '"'
$Cmd3 = $Cmd3 + $f[$cnt]
$Cmd3 = $Cmd3 + '--'
$Cmd3 = $Cmd3 + $revision
$Cmd3 = $Cmd3 + '"'
$Cmd3 = $Cmd3 + ' ' + '"'
$Cmd3 = $Cmd3 + $f[$cnt]
$Cmd3 = $Cmd3 + '--'
$Cmd3 = $Cmd3 + $r[$cnt]
$Cmd3 = $Cmd3 + '"'
$Cmd3
$Diffs = iex "& $Cmd3"
$Diffs | Out-File C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Queries\DataQ\_Diff_Report.txt -Append
$cnt = $cnt + 1
}
$Content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Queries\DataQ\_Diff_Report.txt")
$Content = $Content -replace "`t",''
Write-Host $Content
[IO.File]::WriteAllText("C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Queries\Diff_Report.txt", $Content)
```

Answer (score 1):

The command line you give isn't valid ("p4 diff" doesn't take changelists as arguments, it doesn't take a -S flag, and it diffs pending changes, not submitted changes), so I can't modify it to give you something that will work for what it sounds like you're trying to do based on your description, but something like this:

```
p4 diff -dbn ....sql
```

would diff open files under the current directory, using the "b" (ignore whitespace) and "n" (RCS format) diff flags, whose names end in ".sql".

If you're trying to get the diffs made to sql files between two submitted changelists then you'd want something more like:

```
p4 diff2 -dbn ....sql@251616 ....sql@251674
```

Comment: As I have continued working on this I downgraded to the 32 bit version of Perforce so I could integrate with Excel. Prior to that, my example above was working and gave me the diff of the two changelists. (I am now getting a "the system cannot find the path specified" but I'm sure that is only a setting that is off) **If I am unable to diff multiple changelists then how do I limit the p4 describe to only sql files?**